# Azure information protection

Tags: filenet, azure-information-protection

I would like to integrate "Azure information protection with Filenet" , I tried reaching Microsoft unfortunately no response .

Please help , if possible.

Answer (score 1):

From the Azure Information Protection side, you shall use the Microsoft Information Protection SDK (public preview): https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Microsoft-Information-Protection/Microsoft-Information-Protection-SDK-for-C-Public-Preview/ba-p/176123

or

the older (but generally available, not preview) RMS SDK: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/srvnodes/rights-management.

For deeper insight on the Microsoft side of things, you should be reaching out in a support case.

For the FileNet side, I'm  not knowledgeable.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just label the files inside Filenet, then use the AIP Scanner to target the CIFS based file share (if filenet can expose its files directly).

But if you need labels with protection, then you can very well do that using AIP Scanner, but Filenet would not be able to parse the content as it doesn't understand the protection headers inside the files. For this the Filenet needs to be integrated with MIP SDK using which it can decrypt the files for indexing.